# Simple program unable to get toupper working

Tags: c, toupper

Im practicing with the toupper function but i can make this work, always crash at the point of the printf so i think arguments are bad, or so.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void){

char pepito[10];

puts("\nTell me something: \n");
scanf("%9s", pepito);
puts("\a");
printf("Could be this?: %s", toupper(pepito[2]));

system("pause");    





}
```

Comment: `%s` is for strings, you want `%c` for individual characters.

Comment: Are you looking for a `strupr`?

Comment: i just want to convert random > rAndom

Comment: `pepito[1]=toupper(pepito[1]);printf("Could be this?: %s\n", pepito);`

Comment: Arrays in C are `0` based. I.e. `pepito[0-9]` for the 10 characters, at most `0-8` usable for any character, the last must be the null-terminating character. So `pepito[1]` is the second char in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you only call `toupper()` on the third char (and then tries to print the third `char` as a string - `%s` is not `%c`), I suspect that is actually your question - so your program should actually be using index `1` (indices start at 0),

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  char pepito[10];

  puts ("\nTell me something: \n");
  scanf ("%9s", pepito);
  /* Capitalize the third letter. */
  pepito[1] = toupper (pepito[1]);
  /* print the capitalized pepito */
  printf ("Could be this?: %s\n", pepito);
}
```

Running it produces

```
$ ./a.out 

Tell me something: 

random
Could be this?: rAndom
```